# Surface of a revolving probability density function given in spherical parameterization.

Tags: probability-distributions, area, spherical-coordinates, solid-of-revolution, solid-angle

I wonder why the equation $(2)$ for steradians of a *probability density function* given in [Henyey-Greenstein-Phase](https://www.astro.umd.edu/~jph/HG_note.pdf) function is still dependent on the function of radius $p(\theta)$. So that the solid angle in [steradians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steradian) $\Omega$ is:

$$ \Omega_{p} = \frac{A}{r^2} \,\,\, \stackrel{?}{=} \,\,\, \int_{0}^{\pi} 2\pi \: p(\theta) \: sin(\theta) \: d\theta $$

Although I am certain the source is correct, I do not understand where that equation comes from. Please let me show a reason why I expected the equation to have no $p(\theta)$ or at least to have it as $p(\theta)^2$.

**Surface of an object of revolution:** Let us calculate the surface area of a revolved object first. Imagine you have an upright axis called the *polar axis*. Around this axis is a revolved or twisted surface. A sphere would be an arc with constant radius revolved around that axis. Like the meridian in the following image:

[image: spherical coordinates system]

If we make the radius from the center of the *polar axis* varying, so that it depends on $\theta$ we get $r \,(\,\theta\,)$ and we can influence that arc. The following figure shows the *polar axis* as horizontal $X - axis$. But still the distance from center $(0,0)$ is given as a radius and not as an perpendicular axis $Y$.

[image: radius changes with theta]

Notice, that the resulting revolved object is independent of $\phi$ and is therefore symmetrical around the *polar axis*.

[image: rings around the polar axis]

To calculate the surface of such an object given by $r\,(\,\theta\,)$ with $\theta \in [0,\pi$] and $\phi \in [0,2\pi] $ my initial assumption is to sum up (integrate) each ring around the *polar axis* that the given radius creates at position $\theta$.

$$\begin{align} A &= RingAlongPolarAxis \cdot DifferentialHeightOfRing\\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi} 2\pi \, sin(\theta) \, r(\theta)  \cdot  \sqrt{\Big(r(\theta)cos(\theta)\Big)^2+\Big(r(\theta)sin(\theta)\Big)^2} d\theta \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi} 2\pi \, sin(\theta) \, r(\theta)  \cdot \sqrt{ r(\theta)^2 \Big(cos(\theta)^2+sin(\theta)^2\Big) } d\theta \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi} 2\pi \, sin(\theta) \,  r(\theta)  \cdot \sqrt{ r(\theta)^2 \cdot 1 } \: d\theta \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi} 2\pi \, sin(\theta) \,  r(\theta)  \cdot  r(\theta) \: d\theta \\
& = \int_{0}^{\pi} 2\pi \, sin(\theta) \,  r(\theta)^2 \: d\theta \\
\end{align} $$

This seems to be correct because for a constant $r$ it yields the well known surface area of a sphere: $A=4\pi \, r^2$. But in here the radius function is squared. In the integral in question $p(\theta)$ is not squared.

***Surface area in steradian:*** To get to $\Omega$ which is in steradian we need to calculate the surface area per $radius^2$. Let us calculate $\Omega$ of a sphere by putting the integral equation into the steradian definition:

$$ \begin{align}
 \Omega &= \frac{A}{r^2} \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi}  \frac{2\pi \, sin(\theta) \, r(\theta)^2}{r(\theta)^2} \: d\theta \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} 2\pi \, sin(\theta)  \: d\theta \\
&= 2\pi  \int_{0}^{\pi} sin(\theta)  \: d\theta \\
&= 2\pi \, 2 = 4 \, \pi \\
\end{align} $$

As I can see, there is a good reason why a sphere has $4\,\pi$ steradians, regardless of its size and why steradians loose the unit of area e.g. $m^2 \Rightarrow$ the radius is just cancelled out and with it goes the unit of length (squared).

***Questions:***

1. So why is the function that produces the radius dependent of $\theta$ still in the integral equation (2) for the surface area of the Henyey Greenstein function?
2. If $p(\theta)$ is still in the equation how can it produce a unitless steradian value?

Comment: That paper *never* refers to the integral you have labeled $\Omega_p$ as being a "surface area in steradians $\Omega$" (this is not an "area" - the correct name is "solid angle"). What that integral gives is the probability that an event will occur within the solid angle. And of course the probability is going to equal an integral of the probability density.

Comment: So to calculate the integral of solid angle of an object of revolution I should not start with the surface area and then divide by $r^2$ (making it difficult to obtain $r^2$ out of a function $r\,(\theta)$). I should instead integrate the differential element of a solid angle $\delta\Omega = sin\,\theta\,\, d\theta \,\, d\phi$ over all $\theta$?

Comment: If the surface you are integrating the solid angle is part of a sphere, then $r$ is constant and the solid angle is indeed the area of the region divided by the square of the radius. But if your surface is not a subset of a sphere, then $r$ is not constant and that doesn't work. In general, $$d\Omega = \frac {dA}{r^2}$$ where $dA$ is the differential of area and $r$ is the distance to the origin.